Jupyter server cant access file 404
I have a notebook that creates videos and then it supposed to show it in the cell output. But there is just gray box

in the server console I can see 404s to a path that is good - I checked the permissions and the file demo.mp4 exists and i can open it in a player app.
I run jupyter server in a venv environment as myself, not root.
How do I solve it?

